# Is it possible to define the TYPE_CONSTANT of a derived class?

Tags: derived-class, guptateamdeveloper

With the `SalGetFirstChild(Handle, TYPE_CONSTANT)` function you can recieve the first child of the given handle. For this TYPE_CONSTANT can be a table, data field, radio-button and so on.

My question now is, if it's possible to redfine this TYPE for own classes derived from an upper class, e.g. two differend subclasses of a data field?

If yes - how can this be done? I didn't find any further comment on this TYPES in the gupta help aside from the main entry (which consists of a list of predefined TYPES) and the two entries for `SalGetFirstChild`and `SalGetNextChild`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Proclaimer: My knowledge of the TD ends with version 2.1*
I don't think you can introduce new type constants. If you are searching for descendants of a user defined datafield class, you could use the TYPE_DataField constant to get the child handle and then e.g. check with

```
SalWindowIsDerivedFromClass(childHandle, myDatafieldClass)
```

if the child window is of the desired type.

Comment: Yes I know, I've done this workaround similar with `SalWindowClassName` as the two classes I wanted to differentiate were derived from the same class. But so I have to do execute "manual" code what I want to avoid if possible.